# understanding CodeIgniter url helper, anchor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having difficalties with understanding ci url helper.

I want to generate url like this

```
 <a href="/company/aboutus" title="About us">About us</a>
```

I tried with following

```
<?=anchor("company/aboutus",lang('aboutCompany'), "title=lang('aboutCompany')")?>
```

first two segments are ok, url address and name of that link. Problem is with title, it is rendered as `lang('aboutCompany')`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Does `"title=".lang('aboutCompany')`do the trick?

Comment: have you added the Languge file from wer u are acessing lang

Comment: thats not the problem here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for your problem. Use array as attributes in the third parameter. Also instead of usuall call use `site_url()` helper

```
<?= anchor(site_url('company/aboutus'),lang('aboutCompany'), array('title' => lang('aboutCompany'))) ?>
```

Comment: `anchor(site_url())` thats redundant. `anchor()` does this already.

Comment: sorry for that `anchor` does not do it properly. imagine a scanrio where you are using language in the url. also it is a good practice to call the whole url instead of partial. This has some drawbacks you will know

Comment: @raheelshan That makes no sense; `anchor()` checks the URI parameter for a full URL. If it doesn't find one, it calls `site_url()`. It is completely redundant to put it there yourself, unless you have modified one or more of those functions.

Comment: `unless you have modified one or more of those functions` of course using language you modify the `site_url` but not `anchor`

Answer (score 4):

It's showing as it should. The `lang` is not evaluated in the string.

It should be `'title="' . lang('aboutCompany') . '"'`.

OR, with `anchor()` you can pass an associative array as the third parameter so the whole call would be:

```
<?= anchor("company/aboutus",lang('aboutCompany'), array('title' => lang('aboutCompany'))) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
```

or with your example:

```
echo anchor('company/aboutus', 'About us', 'title="About us"');
```

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

If you want to work with the `lang()` method from CI you cannot use it in string, but concate to it like this:

```
echo anchor('company/aboutus', lang('aboutCompany'), 'title="' . lang(aboutCompany' . "');
```